# Coloring days of week in a jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to highlight some days of the week, but my code doesn't work.
I think the problem is the double datepicker call but I don't know how to do otherwise.

```js
var date = new Date();
var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1);
var end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 2, date.getDate())

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "<%=request.getAttribute("
    giorni ")%>",
    startDate: today,
    endDate: end,
  });

  $('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      if (day == 0 || day == 4) {
        return [true, "Highlighted", date];
      }
      return [true, '', ''];
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.Highlighted {
  background-color: Green !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: White !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data" id="txtDate">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the third return element `date`. It needs to be a **string**. Type of date is object

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

**beforeShowDay**

A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:

- `[0]`: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
- `[1]`: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default
  presentation
- `[2]`: an optional popup tooltip for this date

```js
var date = new Date();
var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1);
var end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 2, date.getDate())
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
    startDate: today,
    endDate: end,
  });


  $('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      if (day == 0 || day == 4) {
        return [true, "Highlighted", date.toDateString()]; // date.toDateString() or ''
      }
      return [true, '', ''];
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.Highlighted {
  background-color: Green !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: White !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' />

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="data" id="txtDate" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to combine the two datepicker functions.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "<%=request.getAttribute("giorni")%>",
    startDate : today,
    endDate : end,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();

        if (day == 0 || day == 4) {
            return [true, "Highlighted", date];
        }

        return [true, '', ''];
    }
});
```